# HP Pavilion G6 has no "HP_Tools" partition after drive change

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, oem, hp

So, I had this HP Pavilion G6 from 2011. I recently found it and tried to use it, but the hard disk was broken. I changed it, and installed Windows 10 from USB/ISO downloaded from Microsoft's site.

Almost everything is working OK, but there is a problem: (when the PC is off), when I press the F5 key, the PC starts up, and it shows a BIOS Error 501 or something, I found out that's because I don't have the HP_Tools Partition on my drive (as I installed the "vanilla" Windows and not the OEM, I suppose).

My question is: can I rebuild/create a working/populated HP_Tools partition?
Or download an OEM ISO?

Thanks

Comment: Try ordering recovery discs from HP>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bph07143#AbT2

Comment: If no longer available try this site, it is safe>>>>>http://www.computersurgeons.com/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

HP_Tools Partition contains Hardware diagnostics, which is important when
diagnosing a problem, but is not essential for booting.
If you have tried to run the diagnostics, then it's only natural that
it failed.

According to
[HP PCs - 500, 501, or 502 Error Displays on a Black Screen](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01443485)
the BIOS problem is either with a corrupt BIOS or with a missing
EFI partition. The later is unlikely in view of the age of the computer.

You may download a BIOS update from the HP website at the
[HP Customer Support - Software and Driver Downloads](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers)
page.

When installing Windows, assure you are using a non-EFI boot and that
the BIOS is set to Legacy boot (if it has such an option).

Comment: Yes, my PC is non-EFI, and Windows runs in BIOS mode; that's not my question. I am asking how/if I can re-create the HP_Tools partition on the new disk. The HP site didn't help, as it didn't show correctly, I'll try again later with a different browser. But anyway, I don't think this is an issue I can fix by updating the BIOS, as I think I have the latest update, I'll check, that later also... Thanks anyway

Comment: You need to find an HP boot installation media for Windows, for it to create this partition. If you don't need to update the BIOS, it's better to avoid it on such an old computer.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote

Comment: While your answer didn't solve my problem (yet) what you say isn't wrong

Comment: I think I found the [HP_TOOLS installation program](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp61001-61500/sp61101.exe). Unfortunately, this is a Windows executable, so you first need to fix your Windows boot problem. You may be able to [download software from HP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers) using the serial number that might exist on the laptop's case. For more than that, you need to login to the site (which I won't do). Question: Can you boot into the BIOS and can you see your hard disk in it. A picture might help.

Comment: No problem, windows runs good. Ill try that, thank you very much

Comment: BTW, yes, as I wrote, I installed Windows in the new drive and it boots OK. And the BIOS sees the drive.

Comment: As this isn't really a very big problem, I decided to give up for the moment. But your answer was helpful in fixing part of the problem, so I upvote